# Dump database data without tables structure in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I need to dump my database data (Only insert queries) without tables structures. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysqldump --no-create-info ....
```

Do not write CREATE TABLE statements that re-create each dumped table.

(from mysqldump man page).